# Modificar el navbar-brand de bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

¿Como hacer que el cuadro rojo se centre verticalmente al navbar sin que cambie su tamaño ni el alto del navbar? Tengo un poco de código de css con el que ajusté el tamaño del cuadro rojo sin afectar el tamaño del navbar.
Sludos!

[image: Este es el navbar]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .navbar-brand {
      height: 40px;
    }
    
    #logo {
      max-height: 40px;
      padding: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img id="logo" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/932211484/cuadrado_rojo_400x400.png">Brand
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ejemplo" aria-controls="ejemplo" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ejemplo">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-center" href="#">Item</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Puedes pegar un fiddle de tu código? No puedo probarlo ni realizar lo que necesitas si no tengo las imágenes.

Answer (score 1):

solo fue necesario modificar el margin-top de la hoja de estilos

```
#logo{
    max-height: 40px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: y sabes como funcionan los márgenes?